# holomorphic function is real analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

$f$ is a holomorphic function on $\mathbb C^n$. If we regard $f$ as a function $F$ from $\mathbb R^{2n} \to \mathbb R^2$, is it necessarily that $F$ is real analytic?

Comment: Of course, since holomorphic function has a power series expansion equal to itself in a proper neighborhood of any point in the domain, and you can write a complex power series to its real part and imaginary part and you'll get the real power series expansion.

Comment: @jerrysciencemath You can post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, since holomorphic function has a power series expansion equal to itself in a proper neighborhood of any point in the domain, and you can write a complex power series to its real part and imaginary part and you'll get the real power series expansion.